# How to disable RecyclerView animations?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using and updating my RecyclerView each second. Since the data is changing I am getting this annoying Android default animations. How can I disable the default change animation? The rest for removing can stay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable animations by adding following line to recycler view

```
recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

This will disable all the default animations

For java

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Internally this is the `setItemAnimator` method

```
ItemAnimator mItemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();

public void setItemAnimator(@Nullable ItemAnimator animator) {
        if (mItemAnimator != null) {
            mItemAnimator.endAnimations();
            mItemAnimator.setListener(null);
        }
        mItemAnimator = animator;
        if (mItemAnimator != null) {
            mItemAnimator.setListener(mItemAnimatorListener);
        }
    }
```

So we are making `mItemAnimator` as null , which is by default set as `DefaultItemAnimator()`